# Best way to store static data in app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new to app development and are learning about creating apps for iOS. I have a few ideas for some apps all of which will be informational apps having little to no dynamic content.

What I am stuck on is the best approach to storing my static data. I don't want to create separate scenes for every page, as that would mess up my storyboard and would be hard to maintain.

I've looked into creating an API that would serve my content. But since my content would change rarely or never, I don't want to have the user to create a network request every time the app launches. 
I've then looked into using core data or the Realm database, but I find it hard to find any documentation on pre-filling the database with data as aposed to populating "as-we-go". 
I've also considered a combination of both, but I also want my app to be 100% offline usable.

I am really struggling on finding what to do. Ideally, I want to go with core data and ship the app with the database pre filled.

I should also mention that I am using Swift. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You can consider using a database manager application to enter your data and then export to a known format and go from there

Comment: If you use storyboard static pages, you can break it up into multiple storyboards to keep your dynamic stuff more isolated and easier to maintain. Added bonus is that if you do decide to change your static content, it is more trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple cases both CoreData and Realm can be o bit overkill. Especially if your data are readonly and fit into memory with no problem I would consider storing them as JSON file bundled into your application.

This can be done in 3 steps:

1. Add `data.json` into your project:

   ```
   [
     {"name": "John Doe", "age": 31},
     {"name": "Jane Doe", "age": 25}
   ]
   ```
2. Define the model:

   ```
   struct Person {
       var name: String
       var age: Int
   }
   ```
3. Load the data:

   ```
   import SwiftyJSON


   func loadInitialData() -> [Person] {
       let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "json")!
       let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)!
       let json = JSON(data: data)

       var persons = [Person]()
       for (_, item) in json {
           let name = item["name"].string!
           let age = item["age"].int!
           persons.append(Person(name: name, age: age))
       }

       return persons
   }
   ```

   Note: [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) is used for better JSON handling.

Answer (score 3):

> Ideally I want to go with core data and shipping the app with the database pre filled.

[Prefilled version of Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057622/prefilled-version-of-core-data)

[Prefill information in Core Data at startup.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544890/prefill-information-in-core-data-at-startup)