# Preloaded Core Data Storage in Swift 2.0

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data, local-storage

I am currently making an application in Swift. I was looking into Core Data to store the little bit of data I actually need to store. I want **three** (permanent number) of these objects stored within the phone at all times.

```
class Location {
    var name = ""
    var type = ""
    var address = ""
    var distance = ""

    init(name:String, type:String, address:String, distance:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.address = address
        self.distance = distance
    }
}
```

These are locations of a sort that users can save within the app. Then they can click a labeled button that will load the text fields with the stored data. The user can update them from time to time if they need to. The issue is not how to save within Core Data or fetch it. ***The question is, how can I have these Entities/Attributes already stored into the app before anyone even runs / downloads it?*** I figured I could just create these saved locations at start and flag it whether or not this is the first run to eliminate the duplications. But shouldn't there just be a way to build the objects into the program from the start and just manage them from then on? Or is there an entirely different method I am over looking?

---

I have never used Core Data but it seemed like the way to go from the tutorial book I am reading. It, along with online resources, just state how to build and maintain Code Data from scratch. I could not find how to build a library in and manage it instead.

Comment: This is out of date, but the concept is still the same: https://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated. Basically, you just need to use the simulator to create the objects, then go dig in the file system and find the sqlite database, add it to your Xcode project, and set it as the default database in AppDelegate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544890/prefill-information-in-core-data-at-startup. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057622/prefilled-version-of-core-data.

Comment: CoreData seems overkill to store just `Location`. Have a look at Apple's Start Developing iOS Apps tutorial in the Persist Data section which uses `NSCoding`